# Через servlet не открываются картинки

Tags: java, servlet

Помогите разобраться.
Через servlet не открываются картинки.
Вчера все тоже самое работало сейчас не пойму в чем проблема.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Servlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet Servlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("<img src=\"images/rr.jpg\"/>");

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Почти 2 дня не мог въехать.

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern> servlet не видит файлы в pages || web
<url-pattern>/</Servlet(или другое ...)url-pattern> все ок.
```

Не думал что это так влияет.